# Function that returns table with an additional column

Tags: postgresql, view, functions, datatypes, set-returning-functions

I want to write a PostgreSQL function that returns a table, plus an additional column. Is there a way to do this without manually specifying `RETURNS TABLE (col1 type, col2 type, ...)`?

For example, consider the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_users_with_most_videos_since_time(ts TIMESTAMPTZ)
  RETURNS SETOF "user" AS $$
    SELECT
      u.*,
      count(v.id) AS vids_since

    FROM "user" AS u
    INNER JOIN "video" AS v ON v.creator_id = u.id
    WHERE v.created_at > ts

    GROUP BY u.id
    ORDER BY vids_since DESC;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This fails with the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return "user"
> DETAIL:  Final statement returns too many columns.
> ```

Fair enough, we're including that `vids_since` column, which doesn't exist in the `"user"` table.

So to fix this I'd want to change it to something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_users_with_most_videos_since_time(ts TIMESTAMPTZ)
  RETURNS 
    TABLE (<<< all columns from table "user" >>>, vids_since BIGINT) 
  AS $$
    ...
```

Is there a way to do this without having to re-copy the entire schema of the `"user"` table here?

Comment: `create view user1 as select *, null::int as vids_since from "user" where false;`, then use `user1` as the function result type.

Comment: I'm impressed at the lengths you're going to in doing this with functions, but as @Abelisto shows, this is what views were invented for: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: @beldaz: Generally true, but this function *cannot* be replaced with a view, since the column needed to filter is not in the output.

Comment: Yeah as @ErwinBrandstetter says, this would need to be a _view-generating function_, i.e. a function that returns a view that tabulates views back to a particular date

Comment: @Erwin I see. Should have read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AIUI, your wish is to shorten the `RETURNS` clause of the function. Not sure if you want to establish a dependency on the row type of the table at the same time, but that would make sense here, too.

The form `RETURNS SETOF`*`rettype`* relies on the used type to be stored in the system catalogs. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)

> The return type can be a base, composite, or domain type, or can
>   reference the type of a table column.

Therefore, just register the row type you desire in the system (once). You can explicitly create a composite type with [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html). Or you can do it implicitly by creating another table, view or materialized view. Even just a temporary view or table for a temporary function (dying at the end of the session). [Like @Abelisto commented:](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144600/postgres-function-that-returns-table-with-an-additional-column#comment274460_144600)

```
CREATE VIEW user_plus AS 
SELECT *, null::bigint AS vids_since
FROM   "user"
WHERE  false;
```

**However**, `SELECT *` is resolved to the list of columns at **creation time of the view** ("early binding"). If you later add a column to the underlying table, the view and its row type are not updated and you get another type mismatch when executing the function. Trying to delete a column form the underlying table *will* complain about the column in the view that depends on it, though. And you *have* to change the view - and the function.

Your function can be simplified and faster, btw:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_users_with_most_videos_since_time(_ts timestamptz)
  RETURNS SETOF user_plus AS
$func$
   SELECT *   -- effectively the same as: u.*, v.vids_since
   FROM   "user" AS u
   JOIN  (    -- aggregate *before* you join
      SELECT creator_id AS id, count(*) AS vids_since  -- note the column alias
      FROM   video v
      WHERE  created_at > _ts
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) v USING (id)  -- USING only retains one id column
   ORDER  BY v.vids_since DESC;
$func$  LANGUAGE SQL;
```

It actually makes sense to *have* this function. You want to filter by a column that's not in the result. Not possible with a plain `VIEW`.

Aside: I would discourage using reserved words like *user* as identifiers. That's a loaded footgun.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Also thanks to @Abelisto. As an aside Erwin your answers here and on SO have been amazingly helpful, particularly the one about [polymorphic types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/1161906). Thanks for taking the time.